# Applications of partial differential equations in material science

Tags: mathematical-physics, material-science

I've been asked to find a partial differential equation that has applications in material science. However we are not allowed to use the heat equation. I have found Fick's laws (basically the heat equation), and the Schrodinger equation, but I was wondering if there were any other prominent applications in material science.

Comment: The question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: Maxwell's equations?

Answer (score 1):

The [Navier-Stokes Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) and its variants are some of the most important/relevant partial differential equations in material science.

Comment: At first I thought I saw the applications, but looking further I can't see how they are that relevant. The article says that the equation doesn't work very well at the atomic level. Could you specify an application?